# Display static text/picture on X3D/X3DOM

Tags: x3d, x3dom

What is a correct way to display a static text or picture in X3D/X3DOM? Using HTML elements really easy screw up the format of the entire website...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ImageTexture](http://www.web3d.org/documents/specifications/19775-1/V3.2/Part01/components/texturing.html#ImageTexture)
Example:

```
<x3d width='500px' height='400px'> 
    <scene> 
    <shape> 
    <appearance> 
    <ImageTexture  url="myTexture.png"><ImageTexture/>
    </appearance> 
    <box> </box> 
    </shape> 
    </scene> 
</x3d>
```

And for static text you can use the `Text` node.